# Android library is using wrong layout

Tags: android, gradle, aar

I had developed an android library which I use to show a popup activity
everything is ok when library is added to another project as an aar file, but after I've put it on bintray and import it to another project using Gradle, layout files are loaded wrongly.
Gradle library R.txt:

```
int layout my_custom_library_activity_popup 0x7f03001b
```

but after starting activity another layout is rendered instead of my popup layout which is actionbar_profile
after I checked project R.java I found the same integer value of both fields

```
public static final int actionbar_profile=0x7f03001b;
...
public static final int my_custom_library_activity_popup=0x7f030062;
```

any ideas ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with bintray. There is no difference between including the aar directly or including a maven dependency.  Look for the problem somewhere else.

Comment: And the fields don't have the same value, don't worry about that.

Comment: Please add the `onCreate` method of your activity